# Why does the overriden method act weirdly..?

Tags: oop, tkinter, python-3.9

I have the following code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import  filedialog
import time

class Some:
    def __init__(self):
        self.filename = ''
    
    def browse(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        self.label.config(text = filename)

class App(tk.Tk,Some):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        Some.__init__(self)
        
        self.label = tk.Label(self,text = '--Empty Selection--')
        self.label.grid(row = 0,column = 0,padx = 10, pady = 30)
        
        button = tk.Button(self,text = 'Select File',command = self.browse)
        button.grid(row = 0,column = 1,padx = 10,pady = 30)
        
app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

This works fine.But when I try to override the `browse` method in order to give it extra functionality an unexpected behaviour is observed. In the overridden method the `time.sleep(2)` is executed first and only after that i get the result of `Some.browse(self)`.What is the explanatioin behind this behaviour and how can I fix it to work as expected i.e. `Some.browse(self)` executes first and `time.sleep(2)` executes second..?

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import  filedialog
import time

class Some:
    def __init__(self):
        self.filename = ''
    
    def browse(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        self.label.config(text = filename)

class App(tk.Tk,Some):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        Some.__init__(self)
        
        self.label = tk.Label(self,text = '--Empty Selection--')
        self.label.grid(row = 0,column = 0,padx = 10, pady = 30)
        
        button = tk.Button(self,text = 'Select File',command = self.browse)
        button.grid(row = 0,column = 1,padx = 10,pady = 30)
    
    def browse(self):
        Some.browse(self)
        time.sleep(2)
        
app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is because `time.sleep(2)` will block tkinter `mainloop` from updating widgets.  Add `self.label.update()` at the end of `browse()`.

Comment: Actually i just did that cause i was running a thread at that point which doesn't actually stop tkinter from updating the label... Also `time.sleep(2)` how come that line execute first... Didn't I just call the function in the previous line..?

Comment: @acw1668 I'll try your suggestion meanwhile...

Comment: `Some.browse()` does execute before `time.sleep()`, but as I said `time.sleep()` blocks tkinter from updating the label until `time.sleep()` completes.

Comment: @acw1668 thank you,I used `self.label.update()`  and that fixes the problem for me.As you said `time.sleep(2)` blocks tkinter from doing so (in the original problem i was reading an audio file)...What actually happens here,i just couldn't understand why should a load or sleep task block `tkinter` from updating the label? Could you please write something on that..?Or maybe some articles on that phenomenon.Thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5317403/acw1668) the `time.sleep(2)` function was blocking `tkinter` from updating the label and as he suggested `self.label.update()` fixed the problem.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import  filedialog
import time

class Some:
    def __init__(self):
        self.filename = ''
    
    def browse(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        self.label.config(text = filename)

class App(tk.Tk,Some):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        Some.__init__(self)
        
        self.label = tk.Label(self,text = '--Empty Selection--')
        self.label.grid(row = 0,column = 0,padx = 10, pady = 30)
        
        button = tk.Button(self,text = 'Select File',command = self.browse)
        button.grid(row = 0,column = 1,padx = 10,pady = 30)
    
    def browse(self):
        Some.browse(self)
        self.label.update()    # this lines fixes the problem
        time.sleep(2)
        
app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Even then you should not use `time.sleep()`.

Comment: @CoolCloud Actually in my code am not using it at all. I was loading an audio file using `AudioSegment` which caused this issue and i just couldn't figure out what was happening so i just tried to simulate it using something that could act as if you have to wait for something to happen that's where `time.sleep` came in and i can't forbid reading the audio file cause that's what the GUI was meant for

Comment: @CoolCloud yes, it does work threaded but can you please tell me what changes does that thread cause.i'd love to learn about that.

Comment: Ummm if it is not in a thread, then it can block the code execution and also the `mainloop` causing the GUI to stop resonding

Comment: @CoolCloud Thank you...Actually i was updating the window inside the thread and was loading the audio in the same but now i have got my doubts cleared...

Comment: Make sure all tkinter code is one thread, or the app will eventually crash

Comment: @CoolCloud Thanks for the suggestion